# Are anonymous inline invokable factories possible with Symfony?

Tags: symfony, yaml, symfony6, symfony-dependency-injection

I can define anonymous inline factory (Symfony 6+) like this:

```
GuzzleClient1:
    class: GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface
    factory: [ !service { class: 'App\GuzzleClientFactory', calls: [ { 'withBaseUri': [ 'http://example.com' ] } ] }, 'build' ]
```

or like this:

```
GuzzleClient1:
    class: GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface
    factory:
        - !service
          class: 'App\GuzzleClientFactory'
          calls:
            - withBaseUri: ['http://example.com' ]
        - 'build'
```

but I can't figure out the correct syntax for anonymous inline [invokable factory](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/factories.html#invokable-factories). How do I omit method name here?

Comment: Maybe this bundle https://github.com/8p/EightPointsGuzzleBundle will be useful

Comment: @Artem Thanks, but actually I'm looking for this solution exactly to get rid of it. A simple Guzzle Client factory of 50 lines can replace the whole bundle in my project.